# Consolidate multiple results in a single count

Tags: mysql

I have a table of sales and a table of sales items. Each sale can have multiple items. The sale also has a sales agency and its the agency ID that is used to search (in this example agency id 8).
So the pseudo query is count how many of a specific product type (in the items table are found for a specific agency between 2 dates.

Table layout 

   `agency --->sale--->item1
                   |-->item2`

My query is

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(sale_id)) 
FROM sales_order_items AS si 
WHERE si.sale_id = s.id AND si.product_type ='1')as COUNT 
FROM sales as s 
JOIN agency as a ON s.sales_person = a.agency_id 
WHERE s.created >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND s.created <= '2018-01-08 23:59:59' AND a.agency_id = '8'
GROUP BY s.sales_person
```

If I run this, I get

```
COUNT
1
```

and if I remove the GROUP BY I get

```
    COUNT
1
1
1
0
1
0
```

BUT I want the SUM of the numbers so in this example above ...4 items found!

I am using the DISTINCT because there could be many items on the same sale of the product type i am searching for but I just want to find out how many sales have THAT PRODUCT TYPE rather than a count of items on the order. Where am I going wrong?

Help appreciated

Keith

Comment: You just try with `sum()` in front of `inner select` query..

Comment: Blimey! KMS that worked. It was one of those real wood for the trees moments. Thank you

Comment: :-) welcome!!!!